# How to subset a dataframe and resolve the SettingWithCopy warning in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I've read an Excel sheet of survey responses into a dataframe in a Python 3 Jupyter notebook, and want to remove rows where the individuals are in one particular program.  So I've subset from dataframe 'df' to a new dataframe 'dfgeneral' using .loc .

```
notnurse = df['Program Code'] != 'NSG'
dfgeneral = df.loc[notnurse,:]
```

I then want to map labels (I.e. Satisfied, Not Satisfied) to the codes that were used to represent them, and find the number of respondents who gave each response.  Several questions use the same scale, so I looped through them:

```
q5list = ['Q5_1','Q5_2','Q5_3','Q5_4','Q5_5','Q5_6']

scale5_dict = {1:'Very satisfied',2:'Satisfied',3:'Neutral',
               4:'Somewhat dissatisfied',5:'Not satisfied at all',
               np.NaN:'No Response'}

for i in q5list:
    dfgeneral[i] = df[i].map(scale5_dict)
    print(dfgeneral[i].value_counts(dropna=False))
```

In the output, I get the SettingWithCopy warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I used .loc to create dfgeneral; is this a false positive, or what change should I make?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dfgeneral = df.loc[notnurse,:]
```

This line (second line) takes a slice of the DataFrame and assigns it to a variable. When you want to manipulate that variable, you see the warning (A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame).

Change that line to:

```
dfgeneral = df.loc[notnurse, :].copy()
```